# How to assign a hidden integer value to a RadioButton?

Tags: javafx, radio-button, controls

For example I have Four RadioButtons in a ToggleGroup with integer values 0,1,2,3. When the user clicks on One radio Button, I want to get its value.

I want to use the solution to this to get that value to use as an index to a List.

For example:
 The user clicks the third Radio Button. That RadioButton must have a value of 2.

If there were any other way to assign significant values to radioButton I would gladly hear it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You actually have several options and which one you choose will depend on the functionality you desire. I will present code for each option below.

1. **Use the `toggleGroup.getToggles()` List** - This already provides an index for all of the elements in the `ObservableList<Toggle>`
2. **Add a `UserData` property to each `RadioButton`**
3. **Create your own `RadioButton`** - This will allow adding any number of properties, similar to option 2, but somewhat cleaner code (in my opinion)
4. **Create your own property bound to the index of the selected `RadioButton`**

> **Use the `toggleGroup.getToggles()` List**

If you are adding each RadioButton to the ToggleGroup, then they are already in a List. You can access that list with toggleGroup.getToggles(). You can then simply get their index within the list.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create the ToggleGroup
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

        // Add some RadioButtons to the group
        group.getToggles().addAll(
                new RadioButton("One"),
                new RadioButton("Two"),
                new RadioButton("Three"),
                new RadioButton("Four"),
                new RadioButton("Five")
        );

        // Add all the RadioButtons to the scene
        for (Toggle radioButton : group.getToggles()) {
            root.getChildren().add((RadioButton) radioButton);
        }

        // Now we can get the index any time a RadioButton is selected
        group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {
                System.out.println("Index #" + group.getToggles().indexOf(newValue) + " selected!");
            }
        });

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

> **Add a `UserData` property to each `RadioButton`**

Since the `RadioButton` is a `Node`, it inherits a useful convenience method called `[setUserData()][1]`. This allows you to add a single `Object` property to the `Node` for retrieval later.

If you only have this one value you want to add, this is a viable option and is very simple to use. For each `RadioButton`, just call the method and pass it an `Object`:

```
rdo1.setUserData(1);
rdo2.setUserData(2);
rdo3.setUserData(3);
rdo4.setUserData(4);
rdo5.setUserData(5);
```

The value can be retrieved when you want it later by simply calling the `getUserData()` method.

The danger here, of course, is that it's not really type-safe. Since you can pass any Java `Object` to this method (and will get an `Object` in return), you need to tightly control what is set here and cast it properly when retrieving it:

```
int radio1Value = (int) rdo1.getUserData();
```

---

> **Create your own `RadioButton`**

If, however, you want to be able to manually assign a property value to each `RadioButton`, and possibly include more than one custom value, you can simply create a class that extends `RadioButton` and provide the additional property(ies):

```
class MyRadioButton extends RadioButton {

    private int myIndex;

    public MyRadioButton(String text, int myIndex) {
        super(text);
        this.myIndex = myIndex;
    }

    public int getMyIndex() {
        return myIndex;
    }

    public void setMyIndex(int myIndex) {
        this.myIndex = myIndex;
    }
}
```

---

> **Create your own property bound to the index of the selected RadioButton**

Again, if you are only interested in tracking the index of the selected `RadioButton`, you can create an `IntegerProperty` and bind it to an `IntegerBinding` that is updated whenever the `RadioButton` selection changes.

```
// Create a property to hold the index value of the currently selected RadioButton
IntegerBinding selectedRadioButtonIndexBinding = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() ->
                group.getToggles().indexOf(group.getSelectedToggle()), group.getToggles(), group.selectedToggleProperty());
IntegerProperty selectedRadioButtonIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
selectedRadioButtonIndex.bind(selectedRadioButtonIndexBinding);
```

At that point, you just need to add a `Listener` to the new property:

```
selectedRadioButtonIndex.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(newValue);
});
```

Comment: Alternatives to extending `RadioButton` would be using [`userData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData-java.lang.Object-) or [`properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties--) to store the value.

Comment: Or `Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> group.getToggles().indexOf(group.getSelectedToggle()), group.getToggles(), group.selectedToggleProperty())`.

Comment: Thank you for the alternatives, @fabian and @Jai! I've updated my answer to include them.